# Junior SharePoint developer is looking for good beginner books!

Tags: developer, books

I have a bachelor in computer science degree, and I just got a new job as a junior SharePoint developer. (The company know that I am completely new on SharePoint)

But I of course want to get good on SharePoint, as soon as possible. I do some basic SharePoint programming during work time as well as some self-studying. 
But I am really looking for a good beginners’ book, that will help me learn the SharePoint concepts such as Lists, Workflows, timer jobs, sites, farm, site collection, content databases and so on. But then of course focus more on the development aspect of SharePoint because I am supposed to be a SharePoint developer after all.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question will probably be closed as it will turn into more of an opinion based response rather than factual/answers.

But in the meantime, I would suggest looking into the following to get started:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt674607.aspx
- [Pluralsight.com](http://pluralsight.com)
- [linkedin.com/learning](http://linkedin.com/learning)
- [markrackley.net](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/03/12/so-you-still-want-to-be-a-sharepoint-developer/)

There is a ton of reading and blogs on Microsoft, so really the first link would be a decent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would start here: [Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892186(v=office.12).aspx)

Yes, it's an old book but, IMHO, it'll teach you the foundations of SharePoint development better than any other single resource.

If you have a Pluralsight subscription you can get basically the same material from the SharePoint 2007 Developer Ramp-Up series by David Mann

It's up to you after that, there are so many different ways to go. Some topics to explore are:

- Development and deployment models (Farm solutions, sandbox solutions, add-in model, SharePoint Framework)
- APIs (Server Object Model, Client Object Model, REST API)
- SharePoint architecture (Farms, web applications, site collections, IIS, SharePoint system folders)
- Visual Studio tooling (Solution projects, add-in projects)
- Power User tools (SharePoint Designer, InfoPath, Flow)
- JavaScript injection (a.k.a. citizen development)
- etc, etc, etc

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a great site to bounce questions off of:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/